# Join three tables with primary key in one and foreign key in other two tables

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjQLk.png)

```
$query="SELECT i.trans_date, f.col_code,f.trans_qty ,t.dept_code 
        FROM table1 AS i 
        LEFT JOIN table2 AS f 
        ON f.trans_no=i.trans_no 
        LEFT JOIN table3 AS t 
        ON t.trans_no=i.trans_no";

trans_no --> Primary key in table 1
trans_no --> Foreign key in table 2,3
```

I am trying to fetch the above fields from the 3 tables but not getting it?

I wanna fetch `date(tbl1),qty(tbl2),col_code(tbl2),col_code(tbl3),dept_code(tbl3)`..
Plz Help

Comment: If you want `col_code(tbl3)` you'll have to add it in your request first, to do that you have to add an alias on `f.col_code` and `t.col_code` because the column name is the same. By example : `f.col_code as col_code_t2, t.col_code as col_code_t3`

Comment: I got it....Thank u !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't have the same key values. Please check the row data in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should use alias for columns  col_code  for avoid ambiguity ( and related  query error  ) due the fact these column name is present in tow different tables  involved  in the same query 
eg you could add the alias  col_code_t2 and cold_code_t3

```
query="Select i.trans_date
  , f.col_code col_code_t2

  , f.trans_qty 
  , t.col_code cold_code_t3
  , t.dept_code 
from table1 AS i 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS f ON f.trans_no=i.trans_no 
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t ON t.trans_no=i.trans_no";
```